# Jquery load more/less action script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the below code that is hiding the articles that has empty data-price id, and has load more/less functionality.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#hotel-list article:gt(4)').hide();
     $('#loadMore').click(function () {
         $('article').filter(function () {
             return $(this).data('price') != '' && $(this).css("display") == "none"
         }).show();
     });
     $('#showLess').click(function () {
         $('#hotel-list article').not(':lt(4)').hide();
     });
 });
```

But i realize that most of the articles has data-price equal to 0 so how can i hide those articles also ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector:

```
$("#hotel-list article[data-price=0]").hide();
```